# In the book series Monster Hunter International, how much does Monster Hunter International take of a PUFF bounty?

Tags: urban-fantasy, monster-hunter-international

I'm seeing all kinds of conflicting information when looking this up and don't remember exactly what it was from the books in the novel series I've read, but I could have sworn it was much higher.

I've read Monster Hunter International (MHI) takes 90% and the hunters get 10%, but that seems wrong. (page 137 of the Monster Hunter International setting book for Savage Worlds)

I've also found a forum post discussing the novel series, where people said MHI takes 20% for main teams and 30% non-core teams, then the Monster Control Bureau (MCB) takes another 30% which leaves 40-50% for the hunter team. Which sounds more correct, but the numbers don't ring a bell and I've read the whole series.

Does anyone know what the fiction in the novels says? Maybe with some references?

Comment: I just checked the *Savage Worlds* handbook for the series, and unfortunately, it doesn't mention anything about splits other than noting that an assist is typically a third the value of a full bounty.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Yeah, this is actually related to the Savage Worlds MHI setting by Gallant Knight Games. On page 137 of the setting book it says the hunters get 10%, but I could have sworn the fiction in the novel is much higher. There is a random forum post discussion about the novels I found that mentioned the other payouts.

Comment: Ah. I apparently didn't read far enough. :-D

Comment: Seems low. But they made $1800/ea when their training camp was raided in the first session. I wanted to experiment with buying advances and know that the hunters in the books are very wealthy.

Comment: {waggles hand} I probably wouldn't have described MHI as "urban fantasy", but I can see how it could fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer in the [Monster Hunter International setting for the Savage Worlds](https://shop.gallantknightgames.com/products/monster-hunter-international-savage-worlds-edition-softcover) TTPRG. I am searching for the novel reference to confirm. I've read most of the books in the series, so I can't remember which one I read it in. I'll update this post when or if I find it.

> Here’s the usual breakdown for missions involving a single team:
>
> - 40% of a PUFF bounty is retained by
>   the company
> - 30% of a PUFF bounty goes to the individual Hunter considered to have “primary responsibility” for the kill (usually it’s obvious who this is; in the event of a dispute the team’s leader or DoO Harbinger makes a decision, and that’s final)
> - 30% of the PUFF bounty is distributed equally among all other teammates (or if no one can fairly be designated a  the primary killer, all 60% is divided equally among the team)
>
> On the other hand, if a mission involves multiple teams, that final 30% earned on each kill by either team is put into a pool, and the entire pool divided equally among all teams’ members. In the case of what are deemed “company-wide” efforts, the 30% (or sometimes the entire 60%) is pooled and divided equally among all MHI personnel (including administrative employees back at the compound who probably weren’t anywhere near the fighting).

Elsewhere in the TTPRG, it mentions 10% goes to the hunters but I distinctly remember it being something different in the novels and this is much closer to what I remember.

Comment: And that's pretty definitive as this game had Correia's involvement (e.g., see [here](https://monsterhunternation.com/2017/10/19/new-monster-hunter-international-rpg-using-savage-worlds-rules/))

Comment: @davidbak I believe so too. The writer of the TTRPG also confirmed to me that Larry was actually involved quite a bit with the lore.